# How to run Python with arguments on Bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

https://github.com/CarlEdman/godaddy-ddns

How can I run this script on Bash script with arguments?

And how the output from the this script is saved to a log file?

Comment: The same way you pass arguments to any command from bash or a bash script. Perhaps you could be more specific about what you tried and the problem you had with it? Also, do not put multiple questions in the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3 godaddy_ddns.py [your arguments ...] > output.log`

`python3` is the program that you are invoking. In this case you are invoking the python3 interpreter. The interpreter runs the file (`godaddy_ddns.py`) and supplies the remaining text (`[your arguments ...]`) as arguments to the program. You should read more on how arguments are passed in bash.

the `>` redirects standard output to the file `output.log` so you get all the things that are written to standard out.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

mykey="blabla"
mysecret="blabla"
domain="bla.blabla.com"

python godaddy_ddns.py --key $mykey --secret $mysecret $domain >> out.txt

output:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "godaddy_ddns.py", line 143, in <module> main() File "godaddy_ddns.py", line 86, in main with urlopen("http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/") as f: resp=f.read() AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: OR
-------
#!/bin/bash

mykey="blabla"
mysecret="blabla"
domain="asd.domain.com"
publicip=`wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo`

echo $mykey
echo $mysecret
echo $domain

python godaddy_ddns.py --key $mykey --secret $mysecret --ip $publicip $domain > out.txt
----
output:
----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "godaddy_ddns.py", line 143, in <module>
    main()
  File "godaddy_ddns.py", line 103, in main
    req = Request(url, method='PUT', data=data)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'